# Generate sequence using array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to get a list of integers from 2 to N, however I am getting a weird output.

Code:

```
#define N 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int array[N]={2-N};
    for(int i=0;i<N;printf("%d ",array[i]), i++);
}
```

Output:

```
-8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm trying to get it to read: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `-` is for subtraction in C, it doesn't create a range of array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
int array[N]={2-N};
```

Sets the first element of the array to `2-N`, and as `N` is `8`, that will set it to `-8`. The other elements are undefined, but happen to be zero.

You want something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    array[i] = i+2;
```

Answer (score 0):

N is 10, 2-N is -8.  That is why the first array element is -8.

The other array elements are 0 because they were not explicitly initialized, so are initialized by default to 0.

You could initialize it as

```
int array[N]={2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Faryin.htm

Comment: Save that that only initializes 9 out of the 10 elements, but to be fair OP didn't actually say what he wanted the 10th element to be.

Answer (score 0):

Put that `printf` statement inside the loop itself, properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
int array[N]={2-N};
```

will initialize first element of array, i.e, `array[0]` to `-8` and rest of them initialized to `0` implicitly (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/2455888)). So, you are getting right output.
To initialize your array from `2` to `N`, you need to use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    array[i] = i+2;
```

Comment: `array` is an automatic, allocated on the stack, so it is not initialized to 0 by default. It is undefined by default (unlike a static).

Comment: It is initialized by default according to IBM docs: ` If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type. `

Comment: @abligh; Yes it will. Run this program: `#include <stdio.h> int main(){ int a[5] = {1}; for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d", a[i]);}` and see the result.

Comment: @haccks - you again! this time you are definitely right. I missed the *partial* initialisation. Apologies.

Comment: @abligh; No problem. It happens :)